# Prove that/Explain how for independent random variables $X_i$, we have $f_i(X_i)$ are independent (in particular without measure theory)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, independence, moment-generating-functions

I have seen a lot of posts that describe the case **for just 2** random variables.

[Independent random variables and function of them](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3048959/independent-random-variables-and-function-of-them)

[Are functions of independent variables also independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8742/are-functions-of-independent-variables-also-independent)

[If $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are also independent.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443659/if-x-and-y-are-independent-then-fx-and-gy-are-also-independent)

[If $X$ and $Y$ are independent. How about $X^2$ and $Y$? And how about $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634605/if-x-and-y-are-independent-how-about-x2-and-y-and-how-about-fx-an)

[Are squares of independent random variables independent?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/220377/are-squares-of-independent-random-variables-independent)

[Prove that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $h(X)$ and $g(Y)$ are independent in BASIC probability -- can we use double integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1856507/prove-that-if-x-and-y-are-independent-then-hx-and-gy-are-independen) (oh I actually asked the 2 variable elementary case here, but there's no answer)

I have yet to see a post that describes the case for **at least 3**.

---

**Please answer in 2 situations**

1 - for advanced probability theory:

Let $X_i: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be independent random variables in $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathbb P)$. Let $i \in I$ for any index set I think (or maybe has to be countable). Of course, assume $card(I) \ge 3$. Then show $f_i(X_i)$ are independent. **Give conditions** on $f_i$ such that $f_i(X_i)$ is independent. I read in above posts that the condition is 'measurable', which I guess means $\mathscr F$- measurable, but I could've sworn that I read before that the condition is supposed to be 'bounded and Borel-measurable', as in bounded and $\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$-measurable for $(\mathbb R, \mathscr B(\mathbb R), Lebesgue)$

2 - for elementary probability theory

Let $X_i: \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be independent random variables that have pdf's. Use the elementary probability definition of independence that is 'independent if the joint pdf splits up', or something. I guess the index set $I$ need not be finite, in which case I think the definition is that the [joint pdf of any finite subset of is independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537542/joint-distribution-of-an-infinite-collection-of-random-variables). **Give conditions** on $f_i$ such that $f_i(X_i)$ is independent. Of course **we can't exactly say** that $f_i$ is 'measurable'.

- Context for the elementary case: I'm trying to justify the computation for the formula for the  [moment-generating function for linear combination of independent random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function#Linear_combination_of_independent_random_variables). See here: [Proving inequality of probabilty to derive upper bound for moment-generating functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944095/proving-inequality-of-probabilty-to-derive-upper-bound-for-moment-generating-fun)
- Based on [the application of Riemann–Stieltjes integral (or Lebesgue–Stieltjes integral) to probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral#Application_to_probability_theory), I think the condition is any $f_i$ such that $E[f_i(X_i)]$ exists (i.e. $E[|f_i(X_i)|]$ is finite).

  - This is the same condition in [Larsen and Marx - Introduction to Mathematical Statistics and Its Applications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJqsh.png).
  - I think $f$ bounded implies this but not conversely.
- **Update**: Also related through another question [If $g$ is a continuous and increasing function of $x$, prove that $g(X)$ is a random variable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952868/if-g-is-a-continuous-and-increasing-function-of-x-prove-that-gx-is-a-ra) --> More generally for what functions $g$ is $g(X)$ is a random variable? Of course in advanced probability just say $g$ is Borel-measurable or $\mathscr F$-measurable or whatever, but I think in elementary probability we say $g$ such that $E[g(X)]$ exists i.e. $E[|g(X)|] < \infty$, EVEN THOUGH this is, I believe, a stronger condition than that $g$ is 'measurable', whatever this means in elementary probability. But then again this is kind of weird since we don't even necessarily expect $E[X]$ to exist (i.e. $E[|X|] < \infty$) or well any higher moment $E[X^n]$ I guess.

Comment: For 1, it is enough that each $f_i$ is a measurable function from $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ to some measurable space $(Y_i,\mathcal{G}_i)$ (which is allowed to depend on $i$). The proof is trivial in light of the definition of independence of $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ and measurability.

Comment: @SangchulLee thanks. 1 down, 1 to go. how about posting as a partial answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. 

For $i\in I$ let $\sigma\left(X_{i}\right)\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra
generated by random variable $X_{i}:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$.

Then actually we have $\sigma\left(X_{i}\right)=X_{i}^{-1}\left(\mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right)=\left\{ X_{i}^{-1}\left(B\right)\mid B\in\mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right\} $.

The collection $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of random variables is independent iff:

For every finite $J\subseteq I$ and every collection $\left\{ A_{i}\mid i\in J\right\} $
satisfying $\forall i\in J\left[A_{i}\in\sigma\left(X_{i}\right)\right]$ we have:

$$P\left(\bigcap_{i\in J}A_{i}\right)=\prod_{i\in J}P\left(A_{i}\right)\tag {1}$$

Now if $f_{i}:\mathbb{R}\to Y_{i}$ for $i\in I$ where $\left(Y_{i},\mathcal{A}_{i}\right)$
denotes a measurable space and where every $f_{i}$ is Borel-measurable
in the sense that $f_{i}^{-1}\left(\mathcal{A}_{i}\right)\subseteq\mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$
then for checking independence we must look at the $\sigma$-algebras
$\sigma\left(f_{i}\left(X_{i}\right)\right)$.

But evidently: $$\sigma\left(f_{i}\left(X_{i}\right)\right)=\left(f_{i}\circ X_{i}\right)^{-1}\left(\mathcal{A}_{i}\right)=X_{i}^{-1}\left(f_{i}^{-1}\left(\mathcal{A}_{i}\right)\right)\subseteq X_{i}^{-1}\left(\mathscr{B}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\right)=\sigma\left(X_{i}\right)$$
So if $\left(1\right)$ is satisfied for the $\sigma\left(X_{i}\right)$
then **automatically** it is satisfied for the smaller $\sigma\left(f_{i}\left(X_{i}\right)\right)$.

2)

The concept **independence** of random variables has impact on PDF's and calculation of moments, but its definition stands completely loose from it. Based on e.g. a split up of PDF's it can be deduced that there is independence but things like that must not be promoted to the status of "definition of independence". In situations like that we can at most say that it is a sufficient (not necessary) condition for independence. If we wonder: "what is needed for the $f_i(X_i)$ to be independent?" then we must focus on the definition of independence (not sufficient conditions). Doing so we find that measurability of the $f_i$ is enough whenever the $X_i$ are independent already.

**BCLC edit: (let drhab edit this part further):** There's no 'measurable' in elementary probability, so we just say 'suitable' or 'well-behaved' in that whatever functions that students of elementary probability will encounter, we hope that they are suitable. Probably, some textbooks will use weaker conditions than 'measurable' that will be used as the definition of independence for that book.

**Edit**: Functions that are not measurable (or not suitable, if you like) are in usual context very rare. The axiom of choice is needed to prove the existence of such functions. In that sense you could say that constructible functions (no arbitrary choice function is needed) are suitable.

Comment: 'measurability of the fi' --> what does measurability mean for elementary probability? :|

Comment: i really think it's like any $f_i$ s.t. $E[f_i(X_i)]$ exists

Comment: things like that must not be promoted to the status of "definition of independence" --> what are you talking about? this is elementary probability. splitting up of pdf IS the definition of independence here. of course it's necessarily weaker than the definition of advanced probability where pdf's are not assumed (but as i recall it's still weaker than the definition of advanced probability EVEN IF pdf's are assumed)

Comment: things like that must not be promoted to the status of "definition of independence" --> it's like i think in elem prob, 'distribution' usually refers to pdf while in adv prob, 'distribution' usually refers to cdf (since pdf doesn't always exist)

Comment: Do you agree with the **definition** of independence that I gave in my answer? What are you after: one definition or more than one definition? What do you mean with "elementary probability"?

Comment: by elementary probability i mean no measure theory eg Larsen and Marx, as I mention in my answer

Comment: Are things in what you call "elementary probability" essentially different than in probability theory? It may seem so but I am telling you they are not. If they would be different then next to "probability theory" we would also have "elementary probability theory". This with inconveniences arising from differences and no profit at all.

Comment: What I see by Larsen and Marx is just [LOTUS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician). If you want to avoid the underlying theory then you can do that by using this as "definition" for expectation. A reference to the real definition is left out. This because that cannot be without going deeper into the stuff (which is to be avoided in that context).

Comment: Measurable function for "elementary probability"?... If in elementay probability the measure theory is avoided then label it as e.g. "suitable function". This without defining "suitable". Practically every function that is encountered will be suitable. They surely do not have to be bounded (or satisfy other strong conditions).

Comment: thanks drhab. LOL at the 'suitable'. so true. so true. actually i remember instead of 'suitable', the term in calculus 2 is like '[well-behaved](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206/what-exactly-does-it-mean-for-a-function-to-be-well-behaved)'. ah weasel words in undergrad. good times. good times.

Comment: anyhoo, i was thinking the condition for lotus can also be used as the condition for independence here: For any $i$, let's assume $f_i$ is s.t. $E[f_i(X_i)]$ exists, i.e. $E[|f_i(X_i)|] < \infty$. 1 - it works right? 2 - also, i think this condition is weaker than bounded but stronger than the advanced probability definition of independence. is this right?

Comment: 3 - drhab, btw, how do you justify the computation for the mgf of a (finite) linear combination of independent random variables in elementary probability? this is the main motivation for this question (though not necessarily a/the main point). I think actually we don't really need the full strength of like arbitrary $f_i$ since our $f_i$ here is just (scalar) multiplication $f_i := a_i x_i$. Edit: Oh wait I think this is easy. If each $X_i$ has a pdf, as they usually do in elementary probability, then...

Comment: ... so does each $a_i X_i$ aaaand the joint pdf of the $a_i X_i$ splits up if the joint pdf of the $X_i$ splits up. is this right?

Comment: OH WAIT WAIT NO NOT QUITE. the issue is independence of the $e^{a_i X_i}$ not independence of the $a_i X_i$. ok so not just scalar multiplication. idk. so yeah, how do you explain why the functions $f_i = e^{a_i x_i}$ preserve independence of $X_i$'s?

Comment: There is absolutely no link between independence and moments. As you can see in the definition of independence moments do not play any part at all. Why do you come up with something like $\mathbb E|f_i(X)|<\infty$ as some condition for it? Can you refer to some source where you encountered this? Finally, I am convinced that my grandchildren are cuter than your children (looked at your profile).

Comment: drhab, I was just guessing that was the condition based on the LOTUS. in fact, i notice larsen and marx doesn't have mgf of sums of independent random variables (but i could swear they did in a previous edition). ok how do you justify $E[e^{aX_1}e^{aX_2}] = E[e^{aX_1}] E[e^{aX_2}]$ ? (could be different $a_i$, but whatever. i just used the same $a_i$ because that's how it goes in the other post). Also, i was comparing my children with your children, not my children with your *grand*children. lol.

Comment: drhab? $ \  \ \ $

Comment: If $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent then so are $e^{aX_1}$ and $e^{aX_2}$. On base of this independence we are allowed to conclude that $\mathbb E[e^{aX_1}e^{aX_2}]=\mathbb Ee^{aX_1}\mathbb Ee^{aX_1}$ provided (of course) that both expectations exist. This extra condition says absolutely nothing about the independence (which is already there, not bothered by any further conditions whatsoever). Again: independence has nothing to do with means. Independence provides some handy rules by calculation of expectations but they can only applied if the expectations exist.

Comment: lol well yeah but WHY are the $e^{aX_i}$'s independent?

Comment: $X_1,X_2$ independent implies that $f(X_1)$ and $f(X_2)$ are independent (as shown in my answer). That's why. Only extra condition: $f$ is measurable.

Comment: drhab seriously? the point is to explain this in elementary probability. or is your answer really that whatever $f$ is 'suitable' works?

Comment: Yes, it is. It works for any 'suitable function' (in terms of elementary probability). In my answer you find no further restrictions on the $f_i$. Only measurability is required.

Comment: ok thanks. merry christmas, and happy new year!

Comment: @BCLC You are very welcome. Thank you for your wishes and I wish you a merry christmas and a happy new year as well.

Comment: drhab please help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4118686): so there's a similar problem to not using the term 'measurable' namely not using the term 'integrable'

Answer (score 1):

**measure-theoretic**:

The measure-theoretic answer is extremely general. It requires nothing special about the real line or Borel sets, just pure measurability. Suppose $(X)_{i \in I}$ is a family (countable is not needed) of random elements, where $X_i: (\Omega, \mathscr{F}) \to (A_i, \mathscr{A}_i)$, i.e. each $X_i$ takes values in some space $A_i$ and $X_i$ is measurable, but all $X_i$ live on the same input space $\Omega$. No assumptions are made about the spaces $\Omega, A_i$ or $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{F}, 
 \mathscr{A}_i$.

Let a corresponding family of functions $(f_i)_{i \in I}$ be given such that for each $i$, $f_i: (A_i, \mathscr{A}_i) \to (B_i, \mathscr{B}_i)$ is measurable. That is, each $f_i$ accepts inputs from $A_i$ (the codomain of $X_i$) and takes values in some space $B_i$ such that $f_i$ is measurable. (This ensures that for each $i$, $f_i(X_i): (\Omega, \mathscr{F}) \to (B_i, \mathscr{B}_i)$ makes sense and is measureable.) Again, no assumptions are made about the spaces $B_i$ or $\sigma$-algebras $\mathscr{B}_i$.

Now suppose $(X_i)_i$ is an independent family under some probability measure $P$ on $(\Omega, \mathscr{F})$, i.e. that for any finite subset $J \subseteq I$ of indices and any measurable subsets $U_i \in \mathscr{A}_i$ one has
$$P(X_i \in U_i \text{ for all } i \in J) = \prod_{i \in J} P(X_i \in U_i).$$

Then we claim that $(f_i(X_i))_{i \in I}$ is also an independent family under $P$.
Indeed, let $J \subseteq I$ be some finite subset of indices and let measurable subsets $V_i \in \mathscr{B}_i$ be given. For each $i \in J$, by the measurability of $f_i$ and $V_i$, one has that $f_i^{-1}(V_i) \in \mathscr{A}_i$ and thus
$$
P(f_i(X_i) \in V_i \text{ for all } i \in J) 
= P(X_i \in f^{-1}_i(V_i) \text{ for all } i \in J)
$$
$$
= \prod_{i \in J} P(X_i \in f^{-1}_i(V_i))
$$
$$
= \prod_{i \in J} P(f_i(X_i) \in V_i).
$$
Thus, $f_i(X_i))_{i \in I}$ is an independent family.

---

**elementary probability**:

As for the elementary probability solution, it really depends on what your definition of independence is. In all cases, the definition only involves finite subsets of the random variables. I would say that without the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra, the proof is out of grasp unless you make extra (unnecessary) assumptions. If your definition is that densities split as a product, then you must assume some conditions to ensure that $f_i(X_i)$ has a density and that you can apply the usual density transformation rules. If your functions take values in a countable space, the above proof can be repeated essentially verbatim replacing arbitrary $U_i, V_i$ with singletons, i.e. look at $P(f_i(X_i) = y_i, \forall i)$.

Alternatively, since you are avoiding a measure-theoretic answer to a question whose very definition is measure-theoretic, perhaps correctness of the argument is not a requirement? Just tell your students the independence condition must hold for "all sets (verbal asteristk)" and then give the above proof without mentioning the measurability. Or if your students are perhaps more comfortable with topology, you could use only continuous functions and look at preimages of open sets.

Comment: thanks nullUser! so basically just suitable/well-behaved sets and suitable/well-behaved functions for random variables that have pdfs?

Comment: nullUser please help [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4118686): so there's a similar problem to not using the term 'measurable' namely not using the term 'integrable'