# MGF of a sum = Product of MGFs

Tags: probability-distributions, independence, moment-generating-functions

So my book says the following:

The moment generating function for the geometric distribution is: $g(t) = \cfrac{pe^t}{1-e^t(1-p)}$
where $|e^t(1-p)| <1$ of course for the geometric series to converge.

The moment generating function for negative binomial distribution is:
$$
g(t) = \left(\frac{pe^t}{1-e^t(1-p)}\right)^r,
$$
where $r$ is the number of geometric random variables you sum up for the negative binomial.

My books says that you just take the moment generating function for the geometric distribution to the r power to find the moment generating function for the negative binomial distribution a**s the moment generating function of a sum of independent random variables is equal to the product of each variables moment generating function**, but is my question is why is the bolded statement true? Can someone explain this to me?

Thank You!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Can you do it for two random variables?

Comment: @saulspatz Maybe OP doesn't know axiom of choice? See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3944284/prove-that-for-independent-random-variables-x-i-we-have-f-ix-i-are-indepe).

Comment: YoGoodSlope, are you sure you understand why $e^{tX}$ and $e^{tY}$ are independent just because $X$ and $Y$ are independent? i'm curious how probability without measure theory is taught in your classes

Comment: Yes I understand, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables and $Z=X+Y$. Then,
$$
M_Z(t)
 = \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tZ}\right]
 = \mathbb{E} \left[e^{t(X+Y)}\right]
 = \mathbb{E} \left[e^{tX} e^{tY}\right]
$$

can you take it from here?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123545/discussion-on-answer-by-gt6989b-mgf-of-a-sum-product-of-mgfs).